# Unit testing http requests to rest api

Tags: c#, unit-testing, http

I have a C# library that gets data from public api.
trying to get into TDD and was wondering how to unit test a library that the main focus of it is to get data from the server and convert the json to .net objects. (Basically handling the http requests along with limiting and error handling and some configuration settings)
I know you should mock some sort of database but not sure how exactly. And i've read that the tests should run all the time even with internet connection off.

Comment: If you're using `HttpClient`, you could make a mock `HttpClientHandler`.

Comment: You probably should separate 'getting data' as a service layer from 'converting to .net objects' as pure domain. In this instance you can design classes without external dependencies and cover them with good unit tests, that wouldn'd need internet connection. As for service layer, it should thin and ancillary. And you can cover it with integration tests.

Comment: I think i will give John's advice a try. After considering all the options. I want to be able to test things related to the HttpClient object since there will be error handling closely related to that

Answer (score 0):

You can implement only integration testing. You also can test your code with internet connection off - just create a kind of wrapper. Among various design patterns the most appropriate is Facade for this kind of task. Create Facade around third-party library so you can mock this facade in future and make it produce desired/undesired results so you can unit test your classes. But:
**Don't test or mock what you don't own**